# Traverse through linked objects

Tags: java, json, tree, traversal

I have this object, where each Rule stores a list of Rules:

```
public class Rule {

    private String name;
    private String condition;
    private List<String> result;
    private List<Rule> rules;
    private Map<String, List<String>> aliases = Maps.newHashMap();
    private boolean last = false;

}
```

What is the smartest and most efficient way to traverse through all the linked objects, and insert all the "results" field into a list, regardless the object on which they came from? eventually I'd like to have a list:

`List<String> results` containing all the results from all the objects.

I've been trying for hours and I'd appreciate your help. To get a list of all the objects themselves will also help me, like flatten the tree.

Comment: Can the results contain self-references?

Comment: no, they do not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams

Here is my recursive version for mapping list of rules to stream of results

```
  private Stream<String> mapToRules(List<Rule> rules) {
    return Stream.concat(rules.stream()
            .map(Rule::getResult)
            .flatMap(List::stream),
        rules.stream()
            .map(Rule::getRules)
            .flatMap(this::mapToRules));
  }
```

Version for a single root

```
  private Stream<String> mapToRules(Rule rule) {
    return Stream.concat(rule
            .getResult()
            .stream(),
        rule.getRules()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(this::mapToRules));
  }
```

You can then collect this stream to a list

```
mapToRules(list).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a root Rule, do I transfer the initial list of rules that belong to this root as the initial list? because it doesn't work :(

Comment: You can use `mapToRules(List.of(root))`.

Comment: Perfect! just added null check and it worked! thank you very much